# Listview selected item changed color into gray

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image]

When the mouse click to on another control, my selected item changed color into gray, not blue. I want it to always show the blue color for selected items like the `ListBox` control.

How can I do it?

Comment: You should tag this "win forms" or "wfp" or what ever (I assum Forms?)

Comment: In web application or window application... Please specify this in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Hope you are looking for [HideSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx) property. The HideSelection property is by default True. Setting this to false keep the selected item highlighted even if the listview loses focus.

```
ListView1.HideSelection = false;
```

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the selected item in the
>   control remains highlighted when the control loses focus.
>
> When this property is set to false, selected items in the ListView
>   control remain highlighted in a different color than the current
>   selection color specified by the operating system when the ListView
>   control loses focus. You can use this property to keep items that are
>   selected by the user visible when the user clicks a different control
>   on the form or moves to a different window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and create your own ListView control by inherting from the original ListView control and then override the DefWndProc and enter the following code:

```
protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    if (msg.Msg != 8)
        base.DefWndProc(ref msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the selected items of the listview blue when clicking on another control do the following:

1. Set the listView Property HideSelection = True, so the system does not override your colors.
2. For Unselected Items- specify white for the BackColor and black for the ForeColor in the listView SelectedIndexChanged (see example below)
3. For Selected Items- specify blue for the BackColor and white for the ForeColor in the listView SelectedIndexChanged (see example below)

   ```
   For n = 0 To lvwExplPlot.Items.Count - 1

       'UNSELECTED
       If lvwExplPlot.Items.Item(n).Selected = False Then
           lvwExplPlot.Items.Item(n).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
           lvwExplPlot.Items.Item(n).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black

       'SELECTED
       Else
           lvwExplPlot.Items.Item(n).BackColor = Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue
           lvwExplPlot.Items.Item(n).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
       End If
   Next
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
  item.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
}
```